# Keyboard variant overridden misteriously by xorg

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard, manjaro

Iḿ extremely confused by the behaviour of xorg in my Manjaro installation.

I probably misconfigured the keyboard during installation choosing the wrong variant, it's now around 3 weeks that I try to rectify the mistake without success.
When I first boot into the system:

```
ngw@abulafia  ~  setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     gb
variant:    intl
```

Then I

```
ngw@abulafia  ~  setxkbmap -layout gb
ngw@abulafia  ~  setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     gb
```

and all is fine, the keyboard works perfectly.
I've searched *everywhere* where the offending variant is set but no luck.

```
ngw@abulafia  ~  cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-keyboard.conf
# Keyboard layout - Don't modify! Use keyboardctl instead!

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
    Option "XkbLayout" "gb"
    Option "XkbVariant" ""
EndSection
```

And I've used both `setlocalectl` and `keyboardctl` to set the keyboard: both work, I guess they just call `setxkbmap` like I did and write xorg configuration, isn't it?
I can solve by for example setting the kb in the i3 configuration but hell, it's so ugly.
Any idea how ti find out what's happening?